# Filter Top 5 used codes SSR

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I'm trying to make a dashboard on several areas with the Top 5 most used 'Areas' 'Codes' 'Categories' etc.

This is normally within a week date range.

**I'll stick to one of the charts, this is what I have for it (the Where statement is not included in the actual report, only used to check the same date range):**

```
SELECT
    CAST([Area] AS INT) AS 'AreaCode',

    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM gail_hazzards gh1 WHERE [gh1].[Area] = [gh].[Area]) AS 'AreaCount',

    gh.[Timetag1] AS 'Time'
FROM
  gail_hazzards gh

  WHERE gh.[TimeTag1] >= '2016-07-04' AND gh.[TimeTag1] <= '2016-07-11'

  ORDER BY [TimeTag1] DESC
```

**Results snippet from SQL:**

```
*AreaCode*  *AreaCount* *Time*

950,    139 , 2016-07-10 14:57:48.000

480,    683,    2016-07-09 12:56:26.000

835,    41,     2016-07-09 08:57:31.000

835,    41, 2016-07-09 08:48:54.000

835,    41, 2016-07-09 08:48:54.000

835,    41, 2016-07-09 08:48:53.000

880,    156,    2016-07-08 15:47:09.000

950,    139,    2016-07-08 15:26:10.000

880,    156,    2016-07-08 14:53:14.000
```

**In my report:**

I have a circle chart which has a

```
filter of TOP N, set to 5.
Values are: [Sum(AreaCount)]
Category Groups: AreaCode
```

**The Issue:**
It will only get one code even though there are clearly more than one. So rather than a Top 5, only pulls 1 code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made into a stored procedure and added parameter variables for date search.

Applied TOP 5 to the chart

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Area),
                    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[tkg_gail_hazards] c WHERE c.Area = x.Area and CONVERT(date, c.TimeTag1, 102) >= CONVERT(date, @p_start, 102) AND CONVERT(date, c.TimeTag1, 102) <= CONVERT(date, @p_end, 102)) as 'Total' 
            FROM [dbo].[tkg_gail_hazards] x
            ORDER BY Total desc;
```